# Java path to Program Files folder in windows 64bit

Tags: java, 64-bit, program-files

i`m trying to get the default Program Files folder on java. When  I use:

```
 System.getenv("ProgramFiles")
```

It returns "C:\Program Files" instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)"

I can add manually +(x86) but if the user will use 32bit system it will be the wrong folder.

Comment: Create a IF/ELSE to check if 64 bits exist first if not use x86 ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)")
```

You can find the full reference on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows).

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct answer for 32-bit Program Files directory

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)")
```

However if a programmer is looking for the 64-bit Program Files folder but running a 32-bit JVM, System.getenv("ProgramFiles") will return "\Program Files (x86)\" as a side effect of 32-bit compatibility.  In some cases, a programmer will still want the 64-bit ProgramFiles directory.  This solution has its flaws, but will usually work...

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles").replace(" (x86)", "")
```

Which is only marginally better then

```
System.getenv("SystemDrive") + "\Program Files"
```

-Tres

Answer (score -2):

Possibly a try and catch.

```
try {
  System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)");
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
}
```

Maybe the Exception could be more specific but that general idea.

Comment: `System.getenv` wouldn't throw an exception if the input variable is not defined.